# How can I get the new, stricter driver signing policy from Windows 10 1607 to apply to upgraded installations?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, digital-signatures

In Windows 10 1607 (Anniversary Update), Microsoft rolled out a [new, stricter driver signing policy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/) that requires drivers to be signed by Microsoft through the Dev Portal. Cross-signed drivers are no longer allowed. The restriction only applies to **new installs** of Windows 10 1607. Upgrades from Windows 10 1511 or earlier are not affected.

I would like to have my Windows 10 1607 **upgrade** install enforce this new restriction, just like a new install would. There must be some sort of registry or boot manager setting, or a certificate store that could be modified in some way to increase the restriction.